# tika app.jar does not convert the plain test to document (pdf) in jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I am facing this issues even though after adding the .jar file in the lib directory still the expected outcome is not there hre is the question

Response  data tab this error message has displayed
"Missing tika-app.jar in classpath. Unable to convert to plain text this kind of document.Download the tika-app-x.x.jar file from http://tika.apache.org/download.html"

How do i solve this issues 
And put the file in /lib directory

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [Apache Tika download page](https://tika.apache.org/download.html)
2. Click on `Mirrors for tika-app-x.xx.jar` link

   [image: Tika App Download]
3. Choose the closest mirror and store the file somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (it is enough to drop the file to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation)
4. **Restart JMeter** to pick the Tika jar up
5. **Select `Document` from the View Results Tree listener drop-down menu

   [image: View Results Tree PDF]

You should now be able to see the contents of the binary files under View Results Tree listener. Check out [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) for a little bit more detailed explanation and to learn how to perform correlations/assertions on the binary responses.

Comment: I down voted because I don't see the point in writing an answer after mine which is exactly the same (except for screenshot of download). Thanks for your great contributions on helping JMeter users, please note I tend to upvote your answers  when I encounter them but here ... I suppose you're the downvoter of mine :-)

Comment: I don't cast up or down votes so it is someone else. The question appeared as "unanswered" on my radar therefore I didn't realise I produced a replica. If it matters you can merge essential parts of my answer into your one and I will delete mine.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your feedback on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

When I want to make sure the jar is added

I open in GUI mode,

Go to Test Plan and click Browse near Add directory or jar to classpath below

Add jar manually

This will make sure you use the jar on execution

Answer (score -1):

As per http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree:

> A requirement to the Document view is to download the Apache Tika binary package (tika-app-x.x.jar) and put this in JMETER_HOME/lib directory.

SO you need to download Apache Tika-app from here:

- https://tika.apache.org/download.html

And put it in jmeter/lib folder.